# Argparse - SystemExit:2

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, argparse

```
import argparse

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, 
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,  
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

I'm running a face recognition example through OpenCV.
I use 'argparse' at this point, and get this error.

```
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

from this code.

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -i IMAGE -p PROTOTXT -m MODEL
                             [-c CONFIDENCE]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--
image, -p/--prototxt, -m/--model
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2


C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2918: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

How can I solve it?

This is my computer environment and use the Jupyter-notebook

- Python: 3.6.4 64bit [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
- IPython: 6.2.1
- OS: Windows 10 10.0.15063 SP0
- argparse: 1.1

Comment: How are you executing this? Seems unlikely you are using Jupyter notebook; `argparse` is used with command line execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard to answer without you sharing how you try to run the file. The error is telling you it did not find the required arguments passed in when you ran the file.

Since you specified `required = True` for the -i, -p, and -m arguments you must always pass them in or make them optional if they are not needed to run your program.

Answer (score 3):

In an `ipython` session:

```
In [36]: import argparse
In [37]: # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
    ...: ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ...: ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, 
    ...:     help="path to input image")
    ...: ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True,
    ...:     help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
    ...: ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    ...:     help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
    ...: ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,  
    ...:     help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
    ...: args = vars(ap.parse_args())
    ...:     
usage: ipython3 [-h] -i IMAGE -p PROTOTXT -m MODEL [-c CONFIDENCE]
ipython3: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image, -p/--prototxt, -m/--model
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2918: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

I can run this parser by modifying `sys.argv`:

```
In [39]: import sys
In [40]: sys.argv[1:]
Out[40]: 
['--pylab',
 '--nosep',
 '--term-title',
 '--InteractiveShellApp.pylab_import_all=False']
In [41]: sys.argv[1:] = '-i image -p proto -m amodel'.split()
In [42]: args = ap.parse_args()
In [43]: args
Out[43]: Namespace(confidence=0.5, image='image', model='amodel', prototxt='proto')
```

or with

```
In [45]: ap.parse_args('-i image -p proto -m amodel'.split())
Out[45]: Namespace(confidence=0.5, image='image', model='amodel', prototxt='proto')
```

I often use this method to test a parser.

If this parser was in a script, and I ran it from command line without the arguments, it would print the `usage` and then exit.  That exit is what `ipython` is catching and displaying as `SystemExit: 2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set required=True to False